# Why I get wrong date in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Template is:

```
{{ item.create_date | date: "dd.MM.y hh:mm" }}
```

Filed `create_date` has value in database as: `2019-08-22 14:51:59` (timestamp),

Why in client I get date:  `22.08.2019 06:51`  instead `2019-08-22 14:51:59`.

My local time is valid.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(item.create_date);` in the component.ts file to see what date you get there

Comment: Hm, `console.log` gives wrong date `2019-08-22 18:51:59`. But in database field it is `2019-08-22 14:51:59`

Comment: Which timezone are you in? It looks like the date is being changed to match your timezone `GMT+6`?

Comment: I am in +4 time zone, but date in databse is already in this timezone

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kszee2 try following code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client doesn't know the time is UTC+4, so client will just automatically assume you are in UTC-0, hence the 4 hour difference. There are several ways and formats of time stamps, but your stamps should always contain timezone.

Formats with timezone can look like this.

> 20080915T155300+0500 or  "2013-09-29T18:46:19Z",

where the Z means timezone GMT+0. You should always store timestamps in the same timezone and then convert it to the local time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, This will show date as `22.08.2019 14:51`. More details at [Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
{{ item.create_date | date: "dd.MM.y HH:mm" }}
```

Screenshot for the result :

[image: Working example]

Comment: I gives me wrong date: ` 22.08.2019 18:51 ` if to do this: `{{ item.create_date | date: "dd.MM.y HH:mm" }}`

Comment: I need without seconds

Comment: It gives me `22.08.2019 18:51`

Comment: I need `dd.MM.y HH:mm` but it gives me wrong hour and minutes

Comment: Can you try this? `{{ item.create_date | date: "dd.MM.y HH:mm" }}`

Comment: Hm, console.log gives wrong date `2019-08-22 18:51:59`. But in database field it is `2019-08-22 14:51:59`

Comment: Please check at your end. I can see it work on the demo application. I attached a screenshot.